# How to stop service from service thread using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, service

How to stop service from service thread using C++?

Service thread runs a conditional while loop. When this condition is false service thread comes out of the loop. But it status shows as "Started" even though I set the service status to stopped state.

```
    Example:

    flag = 0
VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
// Register ServiceCtrlHandler
//  
....
.... 

 startService();
}
    void startService()
    {
    while(!flag)
    {
    if(!<condition>)
    {
     flag = 1;
    }
    }
    SetServiceStatus(<..>) // call to win32 API to update Service status to Stopped
    }
```

Comment: You need to show more than this to get help.

Answer (score 0):

It is the ServiceCtrlHandler that you mention in your example that will be processing the control requests and eventually setting the status.

Please follow the [The Complete Service Sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to understand the interaction between processing control requests the dispatcher thread and the service main thread.

Also refer to [Writing a ServiceMain Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Writing a Control Handler Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for providing the links. I will go through them.